# Which Operating System is Docker virtualizing when it runs the Node image?

Tags: node.js, docker, operating-system, containers, virtualization

When you use the Node Docker Image, i suppose that Docker is running or (virtualizing) a OS that has a node installation, I will like to know what is that OS, or how is posible that Docker is able to run NodeJs

Answer (score 2):

There are several different image variants for Node - the official builds are all either flavors of Debian or Alpine Linux.

See more information: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/README.md#image-variants

- `node:<version>`

  - Debian
- `node:alpine`

  - Alpine
- `node:buster`

  - Debian 10
- `node:stretch`

  - Debian 9
- `node:slim`

  - Debian minimal